# How do I append children to QDomDocumentFragment object in qt with c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using qt 4.4.3 with c++. I want to implement a [QDomDocumentFragment](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qdomdocumentfragment-members.html) object, and pass it as a return value for a function. I am using it the same way as QDomElement objects, with [appendChild()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qdomnode.html#appendChild):

```
QDomDocumentFragment rootnode;

QDomNode initmodnode = doc.createElement("initmod");
QDomText initmodval = doc.createTextNode("4");
initmodnode.appendChild(initmodval);
rootnode.appendChild(initmodnode);
```

After inserting 7 other nodes in this way, and returning from the function, I noticed that calling [insertAfter()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qdomnode.html#insertAfter) on a [QDomElement](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qdomelement-members.html) node with the returned QDomDocumentFragment was not inserting any new children. After debugging with the following code inside the function, I realized no nodes were actually getting inserted into rootnode:

```
QMessageBox::information(this->owner, QObject::tr("Debug"), QObject::tr("Node has children: ")+QString::number(rootnode.childNodes().size()));
```

The Message printed was "Node has children: 0". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok sorry for wasting everyone's time.. looks like I needed to create the document fragment using:

```
QDomDocumentFragment rootnode = doc.createDocumentFragment();
```